# SSLError when connecting from Python 2.7.5

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests, legacy

I want to make a routine for a client that has Python 2.7.5 installed, the routine must consume a much newer API, but I get the following error:

> "requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure"

It is related to SSL/TLS compatibility issues, but I don't know how to skip it. Although the question is if you can jump in that version of Python?

```
class http_Factory:
    def __init__(self):
        # Lee la configuración desde appsettings.json

        self.app_settings= AppConfig.get_proxy_config()

        self.proxy_url = self.app_settings.get('Url')
        self.proxy_user = self.app_settings.get('Username')
        self.proxy_password = self.app_settings.get('Password')
        
        # Configura las cabeceras (headers) comunes
        

    def make_request(self, url, method=None, params=None, data=None, headers=None):
        if data is not None:
            # Convierte el diccionario a JSON si hay datos
            data = json.dumps(data)

        if self.proxy_url and self.proxy_user and self.proxy_password:
            # Usa un proxy si se proporcionan las configuraciones
            proxies = {
                'http': 'http://{}'.format(self.proxy_url),
                'https': 'https://{}'.format(self.proxy_url),
            }
            auth = HTTPProxyAuth(self.proxy_user, self.proxy_password)
            response = requests.request(method, url, params=params, data=data, proxies=proxies, auth=auth, headers=headers)
        else:
            # Sin proxy
            response = requests.request(method, url, params=params, data=data, headers=headers, verify= False)

        return response
```

Comment: Python2 is deprecated and Python3 is free and easy to install, why can't your client use Python3?

Comment: You could solve this with either a reverse proxy such as nginx which is capable of speaking both TLS 1.2 and earlier versions, or you could find some way to use a newer OpenSSL with an older Python. Not sure which would be easier.

Comment: To add to Julien's comment: Python 2 is dead (unsupported, not even security fixes) since nearly 4 years and that was announced 10 years before that date. Do you really want your customer to continue working with that? If the customer has no clue, you should advise them accordingly.

Comment: sslv3 has been cracked and you shouldn't be using it.  Heck, I think TLS 1.0 has as well, so TLS 1.1 is the lowest SSL version that should be used.

Comment: @Powerlord: *"sslv3 alert handshake failure"*  does not mean that SSLv3 was used or attempted, nor does `SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO`. The mentioning of SSLv3 in many places are just artefacts from how the OpenSSL code is implemented. But its a common cause of confusion and drawing false conclusions.

Comment: *"sslv3 alert handshake failure"* just means that the server did not like what the client has sent. This is a very unspecific error and can have many reasons, like server expecting but not getting a client certificate, TLS stack in the client not matching what the server expects in terms of supported TLS versions or ciphers, ... . It is impossible to say what the cause is and how to fix this just looking at the client code and the error. If you have more context (like which server, clients which actually work, ...) then one might point you in the right direction.

Comment: @Matthias,  maybe the customer insists for reasons that we do not know about. so whilst it is true to say that python2 is legacy, the question specifically insists on being legacy, so should be answered that way.

Comment: Python 2.7.18 has much newer SSL than Python 2.7.5. Your client can try upgrading to Python 2.7.18, maybe that already solves their problem. https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2718/

Comment: Which operating system is your client using?

Answer (score 2):

The success of the SSL connection depends on both the OpenSSL version and the Python version (i.e. the `_ssl` extension module bundled with Python). Trying to upgrade any of these may fix the issue. Alternatively, changing some configuration option such as the allowed protocols and ciphers may fix the issue.

If your client insists on using Python 2.7, here are the options I see for upgrading:

- Upgrade to Python 2.7.18, which is the latest Python version from the 2.7 series. Depending on the distribution, it may contain a newer version of OpenSSL 1.0 or 1.1 than the Python 2.7.5 your client is currently using. Also the bundled `_ssl` extension module is definitely newer, which can also help.
- Upgrade OpenSSL to the latest 1.1.1 (currently 1.1.1w). This also involves building Python from source, because its `_ssl` extension module needs to be linked to the upgraded OpenSSL. This can still work with Python 2.7.5 (when rebuilt from source), and also with Python 2.7.18. I'd try both. The first few [search results](https://www.google.ch/search?q=python+2.7+compile+openssl+1.1.1&hl=en) may be useful:

  - [How to install openssl 1.1.1 for python 2.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60213767/how-to-install-openssl-1-1-1-for-python-2-7)
  - https://superuser.com/questions/1443087/can-python-2-7-16-be-built-with-openssl-1-1-1
  - https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/apn0iz/is_it_possible_to_compile_python_2715_with_latest/ targeting Windows

The underlying reasons are the following:

- Secure communication over TCP (e.g. https://, imaps:) is done via various versions of the SSL or TLS protocols. The client and server can negotiate a protocol and a version at connection time, i.e. they can agree on one which they are both happy with. (Except when their configured allowed protocol--version pairs are disjoint.)
- Various cryptographic algorithms with various parameters are used during setup and transfer. One of those is the symmetric cipher, which is used to encrypt all transfer traffic. Other algorithms are used during setup, e.g. to verify the identity of the server and to generate and communicate the symmetric cipher key. This can also work, if the configured algorithm--parameter pairs on the client and the server are disjoint.
- There are various software libraries for secure communication (such as OpenSSL, LibreSSL, BoringSSL, Go's own implementation) which support various features (protocols, versions, algorithms and parameters). Some of those features are disabled at compile time or configuration time. Different versions of the libraries support different features.
- Python (2.x and 3.x) uses OpenSSL as the secure communication library, with some extra code in the `_ssl` extension module, part of the CPython source code. The features supported by `_ssl` are a subset of those supported by OpenSSL. Thus to make a specific connection working, both `_ssl` and OpenSSL need to have the correct features, and these features have to be enabled both at compile time and in the configuration.
- The OpenSSL error message in the Python exception text (e.g. *error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure*) is not verbose enough to indicate which features have to be enabled to make it work.
- One important reason why some features are disabled by default is that it was discovered later that they are insecure. The client doesn't have control over what features are enabled on the server (and also the other way round). The most secure way to make a connection work is upgrading both the client and the server, given that the library defaults are trusted.